# Graphical tool to check controller performance (MoveIt, ros_control)?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, ros-control, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a graphical tool to plot current joint_states vs desired joint states which are output by moveit?
I want to visually evaluate the performance of the hardware controller / check if my velocity or acceleration params are reasonable.
Is rqt_plot the best choice? And what would be the topic for the desired joint states?

Thanks,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377605/graphical-tool-to-check-controller-performance-(moveit,-ros_control)?/) by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2021-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is rqt_plot the best choice?

[PlotJuggler](http://wiki.ros.org/plotjuggler) is probably easier.

> And what would be the topic for the desired joint states?

For the OotB set of controllers from `ros_control`, you could check the `state` topic.

Those typically carry messages from [control_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/control_msgs), which include [JointControllerState](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/control_msgs/html/msg/JointControllerState.html), [JointTrajectoryControllerState](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/control_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryControllerState.html) and [PidState](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/control_msgs/html/msg/PidState.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2021-05-04**:
Thanks, when i use Gazebo, i can check the state from my position controllers (desired vs acutal), when i do plain moveit and use the fake_controller, there is no such state, is there a way to check in vanilla moveit?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-04**:\

> when i do plain moveit and use the fake_controller, there is no such state, is there a way to check in vanilla moveit?

Afaik, `fake_controller` doesn't lead to anything actually *controlling* anything. It's just kinematic play-out with a 'perfect robot' model. There are no dynamics.

You could check the `JointState` messages published by it (IIRC it does that), but that would not really tell you anything I believe. Just what the state of the play-out is.